# Index Match formula not working for non office 365 user

Tags: excel, vba, office365

really need your help,

I have a formula in Excel which is not working for non Office 365 user, the formula is below:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Source to City'!F:F,MATCH(1,('Source to City'!A:A=A2)*('Source to City'!E:E=E2),0)),"")
```

the other formula that i'm having trouble with already exceeds the array limitation,

=IF(ISNA(INDEX('SOB Province'!G:M,MATCH(1,('SOB Province'!B:B=A2)*(('SOB Province'!G:G=E2)+('SOB Province'!H:H=E2)+('SOB Province'!I:I=E2)+('SOB Province'!J:J=E2)+('SOB Province'!K:K=E2)+('SOB Province'!L:L=E2)+('SOB Province'!M:M=E2)),0))),"Out of SOB","SOB")

Current tab where the formula:

[image]

Source City Data:

[image]

Comment: In O365, an array formula is "auto-entered" as array. In older versions this needs to be done by the user via pressing `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`. Also, why tag 'VBA'?

Comment: the formula is for getting the count of order BOL number

Comment: What does "not working" mean?  Wrong answer?  Error? Excel crash?

Comment: @JvdV, i've tried putting the formula under array, it's still coming up as blank, the formula is entered using VBA code, that's why i tag VBA as well,

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, the formula is having error for non 365 user, but working fine for 365.

Comment: How are you putting this down through code? Edit your question to show this. Did you use [`Range.FormulaArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.formulaarray)?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @JvdV, i tried the formulaArray and it worked fine! Thank you so much, still a beginner, but i'm having an issue regarding array limitation, it seems that my formula already exceeded the array limitation,

Comment: The shown formula does not contain 255 characters. What did you do to it that it exceeds 255 limit? You need to actually update your question with information. Other users won't always read down the comment section to get this type of information.

Comment: Now you have boiled the problem down to something which can easily be googled. Try something along the lines of "How to overcome the Range.ArrayFormula 255 char limit".

Comment: It's all good now! thank you @JvdV,